# How can I write a ClassLoader that does this?

Tags: java, classloader

I'm trying to make a URLClassLoader which behaves as follows:

- If asked for a class whose name is in a given set of inclusions, load it as normal
- Otherwise, return a dummy class of my choice

How should I go about this?  My attempt at doing this didn't work - see [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131741/how-can-i-make-a-urlclassloader-behave-like-this) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you cannot do this.  See my answer to your earlier question.

Answer (score 0):

extend URLClassLoader in the method loadClass return super.loadClass(originalName) if in the set of inclusions or super.load(myDummyClass) otherwise...

Comment: This won't work.   It is essentially the same as what the OP tried in his earlier question.